# Canvas ArcTo confusion

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

So I am once again dealing with annular sectors which is not my forte. I can use the `.arc` method on canvas just fine, the problem comes from needing my arc to be part of a path.

So for example:

```
 ctx.save();
 ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, true);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.restore();
```

Works fine. But now I need it as part of a path, so I have something like this:

```
 var pointArray = [...]; //this contains all four corner points of the annular sector
 ctx.save();
 ctx.moveTo(pointArray[0].x, pointArray[0].y);
 ctx.lineTo(pointArray[1].x, pointArray[1].y); //so that draws one of the flat ends
 ctx.arcTo(?, ?, pointArray[2].x pointArray[2].y, radius);
```

That tangent of tangent coordinate is driving me mad. Plus I have a serious concern:
http://www.dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/canvas/CanvasArcTo.html
Makes it sound like an arc drawn with arcTo could never cover 180degrees or more of a circle and there will be times that my annular sector will be greater than 180degrees.

Thanks for the help superior geometric minds of stackoverflow!

**UPDATE**
Ok, so I am having to do svg canvas inter-polarity here, and using coffee-script, actual production code follows!

```
 annularSector : (startAngle,endAngle,innerRadius,outerRadius) ->

    startAngle  = degreesToRadians startAngle+180
    endAngle    = degreesToRadians endAngle+180
    p           = [ 
        [ @centerX+innerRadius*Math.cos(startAngle),    @centerY+innerRadius*Math.sin(startAngle) ]
        [ @centerX+outerRadius*Math.cos(startAngle),    @centerY+outerRadius*Math.sin(startAngle) ]
        [ @centerX+outerRadius*Math.cos(endAngle),      @centerY+outerRadius*Math.sin(endAngle) ]
        [ @centerX+innerRadius*Math.cos(endAngle),      @centerY+innerRadius*Math.sin(endAngle) ] 
    ]
    angleDiff   = endAngle - startAngle
    largeArc    = (if (angleDiff % (Math.PI * 2)) > Math.PI then 1 else 0)

    if @isSVG

        commands    = []

        commands.push "M" + p[0].join()
        commands.push "L" + p[1].join()
        commands.push "A" + [ outerRadius, outerRadius ].join() + " 0 " + largeArc + " 1 " + p[2].join()
        commands.push "L" + p[3].join()
        commands.push "A" + [ innerRadius, innerRadius ].join() + " 0 " + largeArc + " 0 " + p[0].join()
        commands.push "z"

        return commands.join(" ")

    else

        @gaugeCTX.moveTo p[0][0], p[0][1]
        @gaugeCTX.lineTo p[1][0], p[1][1]
        #@gaugeCTX.arcTo 
        @gaugeCTX.arc @centerX, @centerY, outerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, false
        #@gaugeCTX.moveTo p[2][0], p[2][1]
        @gaugeCTX.lineTo p[3][0], p[3][1]
        @gaugeCTX.arc @centerX, @centerY, innerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, false
```

[image]

**THE SOLUTION**

```
        @gaugeCTX.moveTo p[0][0], p[0][1]
        @gaugeCTX.lineTo p[1][0], p[1][1]
        @gaugeCTX.arc @centerX, @centerY, outerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, false
        @gaugeCTX.lineTo p[3][0], p[3][1]
        @gaugeCTX.arc @centerX, @centerY, innerRadius, endAngle, startAngle, true #note that this arc is set to true and endAngle and startAngle are reversed!
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? Do you want to know what to drop in where you have `?` in the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your question/code is not 100% clear to me,

arcTo() still has browser/rendering problems, so use arc() for now.
(Please forgive me, I can't give detailed link right now since I to became a victim of new forced firefox 12 crap and lost years of notes in my ff3.6 powered system, which it simply deleted during it's unapproved update).

arc() works with radians, so do a quick read-up on wiki how Math.PI relates to radians, then whip up some formula to convert your degrees (or what ever you might wish) to radians.
You'll be doing something like: (((2 * Math.PI) / 360) * 270)    *(=3/4 circle)*
By the way: I did not ran into noticeable drawing problems with Radian/Unit conversions and ECMAscript's floating point behavior!

Also don't forget beginPath() and closePath() (and stroke() where needed): don't make the canvas guess!! This is usually key to drawing (closed) paths!!

You might also want to look at bezierCurveTo().

**UPDATE** (on TS' update):
Looking at your picture (which I guess is the rendering of your problem), I think I see what you want: pieces of pie-charts.

This is simple, they are 2 arcs and two lines between a beginPath() and closePath() (and a fill-color).
What you want to do is to center your origin (point 0,0) with translate(). Before you do this, read-up on getting crisp lines: the trick is to translate to half pixels: (x.5,y.5).

Then make one 'main-canvas' and one 'temp-canvas'. For each piece-of-pie, draw a on clean temp-canvas (just set it's width and height instead of some clear mumbo jumbo) and put this temp-canvas on your main-canvas. Lastly render/output your main-canvas. Done.

The 'magic' (plain math) in your script that does the translation between your existing svg-path I cannot help you with, since I('m ashamed to admit) don't recognize any javascript in your updated source.

Hope this helps!

**Update 2:** Actually.. if you would tell us the format of your points/coordinates array.. that would really help! Then we would know from where to where you are drawing.
The best solution MIGHT indeed be to whip-up a javascript function that accepts your points-array's..
This way your coffeescript could simply spit-out your known values (data-format) to the javascript that was needed anyways to render canvas (in html).

Which makes me think.. there must be existing svg-path to canvas translation-scripts .. right? Maybe some-one knows of a tried and tested one and can link/copy it here (for future reference)..

**Update 3:**
HINT: Don't forget: you can rotate the canvas in drawing-mode, but also when layering canvas'.
When you rotate (which works with the same radian-principle mentioned above) the canvas will rotate around it's origin-point (0,0) which is why translating (to the center of the canvas + 0.5px) is so useful for drawing these kind circle-based shapes!!!

Comment: when i was fumbling with it in trusty ff3.6 (and it's counterpart palemoon) toghether with openPath() and closePath(), yes. Just keep in mind that you can also use temporary canvasses, and layer them on top of eachother on your 'main output' canvas.

Comment: But let go of your mental understanding of svg (if you have it), it does not apply equally in canvas. What I'm trying to say is that a path does not need to be one object. This way you can also save and reuse parts of the canvas, they don't even need to be equal size, keep 'm small, then render 'm to your (big) output-canvas.

Comment: interesting, ok, I am updating my question

Comment: @ok I updated my answer, and while it 'draws' it does not try right the way it is now.

Comment: You also might want to check out bezierCurveTo(), see [link]http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-paths/   Just as a suggestion, you could put your problem in a jsfiddle.net case, makes it easyer on people to fiddle around with your case.

Comment: +1 for being so helpful already. Ok So I added a screenshot, the computation of the sector is right, but the fill is coming out weird. I really want to avoid bezierCurves if possible, as I really really have no idea how to make a circula arc in bezier.

Comment: no problem, I had quite some fun with canvas (as opposed to svg). I just updated my answer to.

Comment: I just solved this! The second arc has to go the other way 'right to left'!

Comment: uhm, duh.. sorry, forgot to mention this.. my bad. I figured you already figured out why you start with a point (moveTo()) and then alway's continue your line (if canvas does not have to guess). I'm actually happy I could be of useful assistance. This made my day to ☺

Comment: cool, yeah it didn't register the first time because `arc` sounds independent while `arcTo` sounds dependent to me. So I thought that `arc` would not make a difference as far as direct ect.

Answer (score 4):

I recently found myself disappointed by the arcTo() method (which really should have been called roundedCorner() ).  I decided to come up with a general-purpose work-around for people who want to use the cx,cy,r,theta1,theta2 expression as well:

http://www.purplefrog.com/~thoth/art/paisley/arcTo.html

With the important bit of code copied in here:

```
/**
   if code is "move" then we will do a moveTo x0,y0
   if code is "line" then we will do a lineTo x0,y0
   if code is anything else, we'll assume the cursor is already at x0,y0
*/
function otherArcTo(ctx, cx, cy, r, theta1, theta2, code)
{
    console.log([cx,cy,r,theta1, theta2, code])
    var x0 = cx + r*Math.cos(theta1)
    var y0 = cy + r*Math.sin(theta1)
    if (code=="move") {
        ctx.moveTo(x0,y0)
    } else if (code=="line") {
        ctx.lineTo(x0,y0)
    }

    var dTheta = theta2-theta1
    var nChunks = Math.ceil( Math.abs(dTheta) / (0.67*Math.PI) )
    if (nChunks <=1) {
        var theta3 = theta1 + dTheta/2
        var r3 = r/Math.cos(dTheta/2)
        var x1 = cx + r3*Math.cos(theta3)
        var y1 = cy + r3*Math.sin(theta3)
        var x2 = cx + r*Math.cos(theta2)
        var y2 = cy + r*Math.sin(theta2)
        ctx.arcTo(x1,y1,x2,y2, r)
    } else {
        for (var i=0; i<nChunks; i++) {
            var code2 = null
            if (i==0)
                code2 = code
            otherArcTo(ctx, cx, cy, r,
                       theta1 + dTheta*i/nChunks,
                       theta1 + dTheta*(i+1)/nChunks, code2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Way to resurrect this old question! Good Mutant.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution that actually works.  arcTo in JS is such a joke.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with this myself. Once I drew it out on a piece of paper and used a little bit of geometry and trigonometry, it was pretty simple.

This function will help you calculate the points you need for the arcTo() function. You can move (translate) the arc by adding/subtracting from from the x and y at each point.

```
function calculateArcPoints(radius, rotation, sectionAngle) {
    var halfSectionAngle = sectionAngle / 2;

    return {
        control: {
            x: Math.cos(rotation) * radius / Math.cos(halfSectionAngle),
            y: -1 * Math.sin(rotation) * radius / Math.cos(halfSectionAngle)
        },
        start: {
            x: Math.cos(rotation - halfSectionAngle) * radius,
            y: -1 * Math.sin(rotation - halfSectionAngle) * radius
        },
        end: {
            x: Math.cos(rotation + halfSectionAngle) * radius,
            y: -1 * Math.sin(rotation + halfSectionAngle) * radius
        }
    };
}
```

I used KineticJS and no SVG or coffee-script, so the rotation and translation was done outside the drawing function. Here's the full code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bicycle/nnLRt/11/). I drew out multiple annular sections around a circle, but you can easily modify it to only draw one. Basically, you have an inner radius, an outer radius, and you connect each of them with straight lines at their start and end points.

> That tangent of tangent coordinate is driving me mad. Plus I have a serious concern: http://www.dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/canvas/CanvasArcTo.html Makes it sound like an arc drawn with arcTo could never cover 180degrees or more of a circle and there will be times that my annular sector will be greater than 180degrees.

You are correct about the arcTo() function. It can only produce arcs that are less than 180 degrees. Tangent lines at >= 180° will never intersect, so there cannot be a control point for the arcTo() function. You could just draw two or (I would do three for an entire annulus) more adjacent to each other.