# How to calc the radius for arcTo() with 3 given points?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, canvas

I have 2 `Points` connected by a line, start and end point.

I want to draw an arc between them, but the radius should be dynamic depending on where the user clicks. Thus I have a 3rd point from the mouse, with XY coordinate.

How can I draw an `ctx.arcTo()` so that the resulting line crosses a specific point (the mouse point)?

Comment: What's the relation of this 3rd point to the curve ? Can you draw it ?

Comment: The line should cross that 3rd point, which is defined by the mouse position (the user should later be able to drag a line, and while dragging it changes the arc radius).

Comment: You might be able to convert [this guy's C# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898089/c-sharp-drawing-arc-with-3-points) to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update: this answer is actually incorrect, please ignore it. The centre of the arc's circle will not necessarily be at the midpoint between A and B.*

Let's say the two points are A and B, and the user dynamically provides point C.

Find the midpoint between A and B. This will be the centre of the circle. A line from the centre to point C will be the radius of your arc.

Calculate the coordinates of the midpoint between A and B (the centre of the circle).

Calculate the distance between point C and this centre point. This is the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Calculation the biggest allowed radius that does not wrap curve  for random location position of A,B and C points (supposing we draw with method `arcTo` from A to B through C point.

```
//calculate distance between points and find the smallest one
 const dAC = distance(pointA, pointC);
 const dBC = distance(pointB, pointC);
//calculate angle between ACB (C is vertex)
 const anglePoints = findAngle(pointA, pointC, pointB);
// calculate radius
 const r = Math.ceil(Math.min(dAC, dBC) * Math.abs(Math.tan(anglePoints / 2)));
 ctxChart.arcTo(pointC.x, pointC.y, pointB.x, pointB.y, r);

function distance(p1: Point, p2: Point): number {
    const xDelta = (p2.x - p1.x);
    const yDelta = (p2.y - p1.y);
    const d = Math.sqrt(xDelta * xDelta + yDelta * yDelta);
    return d;
}

function findAngle(A: Point,B: Point,C: Point) {
    var AB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B.x-A.x,2)+ Math.pow(B.y-A.y,2));    
    var BC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B.x-C.x,2)+ Math.pow(B.y-C.y,2)); 
    var AC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(C.x-A.x,2)+ Math.pow(C.y-A.y,2));
    return Math.acos((BC*BC+AB*AB-AC*AC)/(2*BC*AB));
}
```

there is link to answer that helped me to calculate correct radius value
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/797828/calculate-center-of-circle-tangent-to-two-lines-in-space/797891#797891

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for large angles (>30deg).  My own way of achieving this also doesn't work.  I hear arcTo() has issues though, so I'm not sure what's up.  arcTo() has to be the most useless method in javascript.

Comment: @alvrm  probably I forgot to mention that angle is calculated in radians

Comment: I'm working with radians.  Your approach would be correct if arcTo wasn't so useless.  I found an answer that works though https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655832/15956657